SOAP request encoding issue with WebLogic CXF and EclipseLink MOXy
I have an EAR application running on WebLogic 12.2.1 and Java 8. My application uses CXF to call SOAP web service. It turns out that default system encoding (in my case cp1251) is actually used for SOAP request body.
As far as I could find, WebLogic 12.2.1 uses Eclipselink v 2.6.5.
JAXBMarshaller by default uses UTF-8 and CXF logging shows that UTF-8 is used:
Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 2
Address: http://localhost:9088/dump/dump
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], Connection=[close], SOAPAction=["http://.../sendTestMessage"]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope...

But it turns out that the actual payload is being sent in the default system encoding, which is cp1251 in my case. This results in wrong encoding of some non-latin characters.
The same may be observed in the http://localhost:9088/dump/dump, which is a simple mock written in Spring Boot which just prints a HexDump of the request body received as byte[], where I see that non-latin characters are encoded as cp1251
I proceeded with my investigation and got a stack trace, where my non-latin String is being encoded in default system charset org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.OutputStreamRecord.writeValue:280 and eventually I found the source code at https://github.com/payara/patched-src-eclipselink/blob/eclipselink-2.6.5.payara-maintenance/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.core/src/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/record/OutputStreamRecord.java :
            CharArrayWriter out = new CharArrayWriter();
            escapeHandler.escape(value.toCharArray(), 0, value.length(), isAttribute, out);
            byte[] bytes = out.toString().getBytes();
            outputStreamWrite(bytes);
            out.close();

Line 280 is byte[] bytes = out.toString().getBytes(); which means that the string is being encoded using the default system charset.
If I add -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 to my server startup arguments, everything works fine. But I just wonder if it is the correct behavior? Or am I missing something? Maybe I have to add some additional, but not 'that global' parameter?
Here are additional details which might help to figure out the issue. I need to send a SOAP request with one field 'тест' (which is the cyrillic for 'test').
My SOAP client is configured as follows:
<http-conf:conduit name="*Gateway.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client ReceiveTimeout="${gateway.send.reply.timeout.millis}" ConnectionTimeout="5000" AllowChunking="false" Connection="close" />
</http-conf:conduit>

<jaxws:client id="gatewayClient" wsdlLocation="META-INF/wsdl/Gateway.wsdl"
              serviceClass="com.test.Gateway"
              xmlns:gtw="http://www.test.com/Gateway/"
              serviceName="gtw:Gateway" address="${gateway.url}" />


<bean id="sender" class="com.test.SenderImpl">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="gatewayClient" />
</bean>

Here is the HEX-dump of the actual payload sent from the client to server, Content-Type: [text/xml; charset=UTF-8]:
00000000 3C 73 6F 61 70 3A 45 6E 76 65 6C 6F 70 65 20 78 <soap:Envelope x
00000010 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 73 6F 61 70 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A mlns:soap="http:
00000020 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 6D 61 73 2E 78 6D 6C 73 6F 61 //schemas.xmlsoa
00000030 70 2E 6F 72 67 2F 73 6F 61 70 2F 65 6E 76 65 6C p.org/soap/envel
00000040 6F 70 65 2F 22 3E 3C 73 6F 61 70 3A 42 6F 64 79 ope/"><soap:Body
00000050 3E 3C 6E 73 30 3A 73 65 6E 64 54 65 73 74 4D 65 ><ns0:sendTestMe
00000060 73 73 61 67 65 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 6E 73 30 3D ssage xmlns:ns0=
00000070 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 74 65 73 74 "http://www.test
00000080 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 47 61 74 65 77 61 79 2F 22 3E 3C .com/Gateway/"><
00000090 64 61 74 61 3E F2 E5 F1 F2 3C 2F 64 61 74 61 3E data>....</data>
000000A0 3C 2F 6E 73 30 3A 73 65 6E 64 54 65 73 74 4D 65 </ns0:sendTestMe
000000B0 73 73 61 67 65 3E 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 3A 42 6F 64 ssage></soap:Bod
000000C0 79 3E 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 3A 45 6E 76 65 6C 6F 70 y></soap:Envelop
000000D0 65 3E                                           e>

Tag 'data' contains the word 'тест' encoded as cp1251: F2 E5 F1 F2
While I expect the following (I get this when I explicitly add -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 to my server startup arguments, but I believe it should work correctly without adding this):
00000000 3C 73 6F 61 70 3A 45 6E 76 65 6C 6F 70 65 20 78 <soap:Envelope x
00000010 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 73 6F 61 70 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A mlns:soap="http:
00000020 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 6D 61 73 2E 78 6D 6C 73 6F 61 //schemas.xmlsoa
00000030 70 2E 6F 72 67 2F 73 6F 61 70 2F 65 6E 76 65 6C p.org/soap/envel
00000040 6F 70 65 2F 22 3E 3C 73 6F 61 70 3A 42 6F 64 79 ope/"><soap:Body
00000050 3E 3C 6E 73 30 3A 73 65 6E 64 54 65 73 74 4D 65 ><ns0:sendTestMe
00000060 73 73 61 67 65 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 6E 73 30 3D ssage xmlns:ns0=
00000070 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 74 65 73 74 "http://www.test
00000080 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 47 61 74 65 77 61 79 2F 22 3E 3C .com/Gateway/"><
00000090 64 61 74 61 3E D1 82 D0 B5 D1 81 D1 82 3C 2F 64 data>........</d
000000A0 61 74 61 3E 3C 2F 6E 73 30 3A 73 65 6E 64 54 65 ata></ns0:sendTe
000000B0 73 74 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 3E 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 stMessage></soap
000000C0 3A 42 6F 64 79 3E 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 3A 45 6E 76 :Body></soap:Env
000000D0 65 6C 6F 70 65 3E                               elope>

Tag 'data' contains the word 'тест' encoded as utf-8: D1 82 D0 B5 D1 81 D1 82.
